# How large might a paper wasp nest become?

Tags: zoology, entomology, wasps

About two weeks ago I noticed a new wasp nest in my back yard. I generally leave them as long as they aren't interfering with anything, but this nest has suddenly grown quite large and they are swarming when I mow the lawn. From the nest appearance, I was afraid these were [bald-faced hornets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bald-faced_hornet), but up close they look more like [yellowjackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_jacket), I'm uncertain of the species. This is as close as I dared to get with the camera.

[image: wasp nest]
[image: close up]

I am willing to live and let live until October (when the nest is vacated), but I have two concerns that may change my mind:

- How large might this nest become?
- If I leave them this summer, are they likely to return to the same place next year?

Comment: About double to triple that size if there is plenty of food in the area.

Comment: I used a magnifying glass and it does look like yellow jackets.  I don't think they are the more laid back species (European) but the OTHER species that is much more aggressive.

Comment: For a closer look, try taking a picture at night with the flash. Wasps usually don't fly a lot at night.

Comment: Wasp nest growth rate is inversely proportional to the frequency at which you hit it with a rake.

Answer (score 4):

According to multiple reports ([here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2308072/SEVEN-METRE-wasps-nest-police-abandoned-house-holiday-island.html), [here](http://www.worldrecordacademy.com/nature/largest_wasps_nest_22-Foot_Nest_breaks_Guinness_world_record_213346.html) and [here](http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/1366/20130413/millions-wasps-22-foot-nest-found-abandoned-home-photo.htm)), a **7m (22ft) paper wasp nest was found** in an abandoned home in San Sebastian de La Gomera on the island of Tenerife (~100km off the shore from Morocco)!! The nest was estimated to be home to **over 22,000 wasps**! The picture is included below:

This nest broke the previous world record, a nest discovered in Waimaukau in New Zealand in April 1963 that was an impressive 3.7metres, or 12ft 2ins long, more than 5ft in diameter and 18ft in circumference!

[image: Giant Wasp Nest on Tenerife]

**Other big nests?** ...

- According to this [site](http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/10152/20141108/10-foot-long-yellow-jacket-nest-removed-from-sc-camper.htm) a 10 ft x 7ft x 2ft nest buzzing with about 400,000 yellow jackets was found in a camper in SC, U.S.
- Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCoPoqnyAdU) of an apparent giant (6.5ft x 8ft) yellow jacket nest found in Florida, U.S. in 2013. A Picture of the nest is below:

[image: florida yellow jacket nest in 2013]

Answer (score 0):

As to your second question: [wasps do not return to a nest, they build a new one every year](https://www.wasp-removal.com/wasp-answers5.php)

However, if you leave the nest it will produce new queens, perhaps enlarging the change they will build a new nest in the area.